# Android app crash while converting with media codec with MP4 formatting?

Tags: android, multithreading, video, android-camera, android-mediacodec

I have an app which get data as byte from onPreviewFrame and pass to my encoder which is another class implement media codec api of android get data and make a video file. It works file with format "video/avc" but crash fro "mpeg4" with showing a thread error. What could be the reason?

Comment: show some code and also post your log cat

Comment: MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 800, 480); // I get problem here. "video/avc" work fine but video/other" create problem//
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mediaCodec.start();

Answer (score 1):

Please study the excellent explanation at http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/. Specifically, [`MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#createEncoderByType(java.lang.String)) may throw exception. Maybe your device expects **"video/mp4v-es"** for MPEG4 video.

If possible, it is preferred to use `MediaCodec.findEncoderForFormat(MediaFormat)`.

Comment: for "video/avc" App work fine on Samsung Galaxy Note 3 but create problem on Nexus 5, Galaxy s3 neo,. How can i fix it ? any idea ? I  am studying you resource and trying to fix it

Comment: This is how it's built, unfortunately. There is no mime type that is guaranteed to be available on all devices.

Comment: Is there any other API which can give support to different device? Is there any low level API which can give support minimum API 14 to up?

Comment: Check the excellent [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) project. If you check the pie chart, API 14 is not worth worrying about.